# How do I edit the MainWindow constructor of a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf

My mainWindow needs to subscribe to some events from an object. The object is initialized before the MainWindow is created. I would like to pass this object to the mainWindow via its constructor.

However I can't figure out from where the MainWindow constructor is called. Alternatively I tried to pass the object via a member function of the MainWindow, but the `app.MainWindow` is `null` before `app.Run()` is called. After `app.Run()` is called the code doesn't return until the program terminates.

Another posibility would be storing the object in a static class and have the MainWindow access that, but this seems unnecessarily complicated.

I realize I can just create the object in the MainWindow constructor, but that would mean having to put a lot of other code there as well, pretty much the entire Main function.

How can I pass this object to my MainWindow? Or is the MainWindow constructor intended to function as the 'Main' for the entire program?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could do it like this.

First go into `App.xaml` and remove this line `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to prevent WPF from automatically showing the `MainWindow`.

Next right click on `App.xaml` and choose `View Code` to open up `App.xaml.cs`. Inside this file we need to to override the `OnStartup` event.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

Inside `OnStartup` we can then instantiate our `MainWindow` and show it.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    mw.Show();
}
```

And now we can use this to load an alternative `Constructor` that we can use to pass on more information.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow(5);
    mw.Show();
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public MainWindow(int number) : base()
{

}
```

I prefer to [chain](https://web.archive.org/web/20121222061528/http://en.csharp-online.net/Common_Type_System%E2%80%94Constructor_Chaining) my [constructors](https://web.archive.org/web/20121222061528/http://en.csharp-online.net/Common_Type_System%E2%80%94Constructor_Chaining), but it's of course not a requirement by any means.

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. Still this means the `OnStartup` function is pretty much the `Main`, unless you subclass `StartupEventArgs` and put everything you need from the `Main` in there. I guess it doesn't actually matter, i'm just used to C++.

Comment: Is this the best way to create a message pump for the main window of the application when you need a custom constructor? I know in Windows Forms there were different ways of showing a form, but depending on how you did it, it could cause bugs, especially for the main form, so it was more reliable to use the code generated by the IDE. Can you link to an official example or documentation indicating this is a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

You could set the object as the DataContext of the MainWindow by declaring it in the XAML itself.  (If you are trying to create a ViewModel, for instance).  Other than that, WPF will create the instance in a way you can't control.  You could put your own code in the App class to create and display the window, and remove the StartupUri from App.xaml.

Comment: Using the `DataContext` is the way to go in WPF, especially if you want to get into using more advanced patterns like for example `MVVM` later.