# Why WPF Window did not open

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I want to make program name Cyan Pembuat Soal(Cyan Question Maker) I add the startup event to this Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace Cyan_Pembuat_Soal {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application {
        private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e){
            if (FindPlace(e.Args) != null) {
                Cyan_Pembuat_Soal.MainWindow a = new Cyan_Pembuat_Soal.MainWindow();
                a.Activate();
            } else {
                Cyan_Pembuat_Soal.MainWindow a = new Cyan_Pembuat_Soal.MainWindow();
                a.Activate();
                a.Closed += delegate(object senders, EventArgs es) {this.Shutdown();};
            }
        }
        private static string FindPlace(string[] a) {
            if (a.Length == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            int b = 0;
            System.Uri c;
            for (b = 0; b < a.Length; b++) {
                if(Uri.TryCreate(a[b], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out c)){
                    break;
                }
            }
            c = null;
            return a[b];
        }
    }
}
```

But that code did not work properly. What's wrong in this program?

Comment: use `a.Show()` not `a.Activate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to add `a.ShowDialog();` or `a.Show();` in addition to `a.Activate();`.

Not sure why you are using `Activate()`, but make sure that it does what you want it do to.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a.Show() instead of a.Activate();
And make sure that your handler is registered in App.Xaml:

```
<Application 
    ...
    Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Comment: If he uses `Show()` and `Startup` the `Window` will be shown twice. In this case he should use `Show` or `ShowDialog`.

Comment: No. There is difference between   StartupUri and Startup :)

Comment: Ah, confused the two. I just override `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)` so never hadthe need for adding additional XAML code to make sure it picks up things like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166531/how-do-i-edit-the-mainwindow-constructor-of-a-wpf-application/10166597#10166597

Comment: Yeah, they are very similar, but in the example there is no override keyword

Comment: But I want to a custom startup.