# WPF MainWindow that takes parameters

Tags: wpf

I need to start my WPF application with a logger injected on the main window constructor.
Is this flow for launching MainWindow() with parameters ok?
(I Read this "[how to edit..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166531/how-do-i-edit-the-mainwindow-constructor-of-a-wpf-application)" and im not doing it like they suggested.. )

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ILoggingService logger = new NLogService(string.Format("testLogger"));
        MainWindow mainWindows = new MainWindow(logger);
        mainWindows.Show();
    }


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow(ILoggingService logger) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.logger = logger;
    }


<Application x:Class="Test.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Comment: Well, it's certainly okay :) What's your concern? The approach shown in the question you referenced is okay as well.

Comment: to verify i dont do mistakes.. :)