# How to set position of a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, touch

is there any easy way to set position of a user control using C# code? I want to spawn new control on touch, and set its position on the position of the finger. Also it is okay to create constructor with parameters like this:

```
public WebControl(double foo, double bar, Foo bar) //just for example
{
    InitialiseComponent();
    ///Do something

}
```

So, is that possible to set position of user control and use constructors with parameters in WPF?

Comment: What is the container for the usercontrol? (grid,canvas etc?) the positioning system changes depending on the container. On a grid you use margins to set the position and canvas you use Canvas.SetLeft and Canvas.SetTop

Comment: *is that possible to set position of user control and use constructors with parameters in WPF?* No, not like you want... what do you think those parameters would set? Surely any positional parameters must go to the parent of the `UserControl` instead?

Comment: @up 
Okay, Understood. I wanted to use something like my code to set intial position of control

Comment: You can use a custom constructor on star-up. [Explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166531/how-do-i-edit-the-mainwindow-constructor-of-a-wpf-application)